# Monitoring WebSockets latency

Tags: javascript, performance

We're building a latency-sensitive web application that uses websockets (or a Flash fallback) for sending messages to the server. While there is an excellent tool called [Yahoo Boomerang](https://github.com/yahoo/boomerang) for measuring bandwidth/latency for web apps, the latency value produced by Boomerang also includes the time necessary to establish HTTP connection, which is not what I need, since the websockets connection is already established and we actually only need to measure the ping time. Is there any way to solve it?

Second, Boomerang appears to fire only once when the page is loaded and doesn't seem to rerun the tests later even if commanded to. Is it possible to force it to run connection tests e.g. every 60 seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems pretty trivial to me.

1. Send `PING` to the server. Time is `t1`.
2. Read `PONG` response. Time is `t2` now.
3. `ping time = t2 - t1`
4. Repeat every once in a while (and optionally report to the stats server).

Obviously, your server would have to know to send PONG in response to a PING command.

Comment: This doesn't assume anything. It measures combined time.

Comment: Yep. I think I need to have a cup of coffee (and to stop posting stupid questions to SO). :-\