# How to track websocket latency in OkHttp3

Tags: okhttp

I am using OkHttp3 to make a websocket connection to a third-party server to receive data. I want to track the latency of the websocket connection. 
This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9081187/1479478) seems the way to go, but without ping/pong being exposed in OkHttp3, how do I figure out the latency?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that OkHttp should consider exposing to clients, with the existing Ping events.

Until and if that becomes possible, your best best is probably to implement application level pings to the backend for tracking this.